# Shared Sub/Function in Vb .Net Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, function, module

I have 2 forms in a VB.NET application - `FormA` and `FormB`. Both forms have a textbox named `textbox1` and an identical function that updates the textbox from some SQL query - `Sub getvaluefromSQL()` - which is triggered by a button or something.

1. Can there be a way for the forms to access `getvaluefromSQL()` from a shared module called `CentralModule` rather than duplicating the code for `getvaluefromSQL()` in the two forms?
2. How does one get around making sure `getvaluefromSQL()` updates the correct textbox from the form that called it?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not very obvious why a function that does something with a dbase should *also* update the UI.  Separating concerns is a basic programming technique.  But if you have to, simply add a TextBox parameter.

Comment: Yeah, what Hans said. Your best bet is to take the code that would be identical between the two forms and place it into the function in the module and then have the function return the value you need to update the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module with a public (or friend) function.  You would pass the textbox as a parameter to the function.  If the SQL is different, you could pass the SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, having a function that performs action on the database, UI, and maybe something else is a terrible idea. You need to separate your concerns thus designing different functions for I/O operations, UI management, business logic, etc. So you need to change your design a bit.

First off, of course there is a way to place a common code in a shared module - e.g. `CentralModule`. That's what modules are for.

```
Module CentralModule

    Public Function getvaluefromSQL() As String
        Dim result As String

        ' Fetch your data from SQL, calculate as necessary and assign the result

        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Then, into each of your forms do this:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    textbox1.Value = CentralModule.getvaluefromSQL

End Sub
```